# Story ID - giant organic rotating space elevator lifts passengers to orbit

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm trying to remember the title of this novel. I don't remember anything about the middle or ending of the novel; but near the beginning, the protagonist has to get off Earth and into orbit, so he/she/it catches a ride on an enormous rotating space elevator that is a living entity or it is comprised of living entities or something.  Anyway it is a rotating system and scrapes along the earth, the passenger jumps on, and it rotates up to orbit.  Or maybe I am remembering it all wrong.  Does anyone remember any plot elements like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImaginaryEvents' answer made me remember a different Gregory Benford book where he also used the idea of a rotating skyhooks called "pinwheels", *Beyond Infinity*:

[image]

There's a plot summary [here](http://visionsofparadise.blogspot.com/2006/05/beyond-infinity.html), see if any of the other plot elements ring a bell (like the far future setting filled with highly-evolved human descendants, where the heroine is an "original" who has DNA based on humans of the distant past). I remember there was an extended sequence where she had to make her way through the interior of the pinwheel (along with an uplifted animal companion) and there were a lot of strange organisms inside.

Comment: From your linked summary: "It was supposedly based on Benford’s earlier novella *Beyond the Fall of Night*". I guess Benford didn't like the negative reviews of the Clarke sequel, and tried again.

Answer (score 3):

An organic non-synchronous orbital skyhook called The Pinwheel is in Benford's sequel to Clarke's "Against The Fall Of Night", [*Beyond The Fall Of Night*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1107009.Beyond_The_Fall_Of_Night).

[image]

Comment: I feel like I remember a story like this where there were all sorts of weird creatures living inside the rotating skyhook, is that element in "Against the Fall of Night?" If not I'll try to remember what book I'm thinking of...

Comment: The Benford half of this expansion had all sorts of alien/engineered/evolved creatures, and I believe the Pinwheel *was* home to many. But it was years ago, and I don't have a handy copy to check the details.

Comment: Nelson, as you remember the Pinwheel at near the beginning of the novel, I would guess you read the book @Hypnosifl suggests below. If so, you should accept that answer so that this question is closed.